# Saving arrays in Rails 4.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, database

I am having some trouble saving arrays in Rails.

`Rails version: 4.2.3 | Ruby version: 2.2.1 | DB: PostgreSQL`

In my view, I have a collection of check boxes that shows the conferences that my member attended.

```
<%= f.fields_for :conferences_member do |conference| %>
<%= collection_check_boxes(:conferences_member, :conference_id, @all_conferences, :id, :name)%>
<% end %>
```

I put a break point (`binding.pry`) after the create action in my `MembersController`, and surprisingly, it shows the selected check boxes:

```
Processing by Database::MembersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"XYZ==",
[...] "conferences_member"=>     {"conference_id"=>["3", "5", ""]}, [...]
```

Now, if I go to `rails c`, and type `ConferencesMember.last` to check what was saved, I get:

```
pry(main)> ConferencesMember.last
ConferencesMember Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "conferences_members".* FROM 
"conferences_members"  ORDER BY "conferences_members"."id" DESC LIMIT 1

=> nil
```

These are my associations:

```
#=> member.rb

has_one :conferences_member
accepts_nested_attributes_for :conferences_member, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

#=> conferences_member.rb

serialize :conference_id, Array
belongs_to :member  

#=> members_controller.rb

params.require(:member).permit( [...]
:conference_member_attributes => [:id, :member_id, :conference_id => []],
[...])
```

I want to thank you in advance. I've tried *almost* everything here on StackOverflow, but I don't see my error.

Thank you again.

**EDIT:**

More of my MembersController:

```
def new
    @member = Member.new
    @member.build_conferences_member
end

def create
    @member = Member.new(member_params)
    binding.pry
end
```

The log doesn't show any error, it just shows that conferences were not saved at all.

Comment: Is there an error on the save?  Maybe post a little more of your controller and create method.

Comment: Thanks Swards. Just updated it.

Comment: no @member.save?  If you still have an error after that, check to see what @member.errors has in it.

Comment: can you show entire form? .. looks like the param sent to controller is wrong. typically conferences_member should be sent as conferences_member_atrribute

Comment: Hmm, I see what you're saying. [Here's a snippet from the form](http://pastebin.com/usMXj7yD) – Not sure how it helps, but I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Why is there no @member.save in the create action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your field needs to be renamed to nest the `:conference_id` in `:conferences_member_attributes` (*not* in `:conferences_member` as you do now). Take advantage of the form object yielded by `fields_for`:

```
<%= f.fields_for :conferences_member do |conference| %>
  <%= conference.collection_check_boxes :conference_id, @all_conferences, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

You also need to actually save the record in the `create` action: `Member.new` builds the record *but does not save it*. Typically, the `create` action branches based on whether the record saved or did not (due to validations). So you might rewrite this method like so:

```
def create
  @member = Member.new(member_params)
  # when @member.save returns true, it saved to the db successfully
  if @member.save
    redirect_to members_path, notice: "Member #{@member.id} saved!"
  # otherwise, it didn't save because of a validation error, so we render the error
  # to the user and give them a chance to fix it
  else
    flash[:error] = "Member didn't save: #{@member.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}"
    render :new
  end
end
```

Lastly, to make sure your data gets through your strong parameters, check your logs for any messages that parameters were filtered out. The messages look like:

```
Unpermitted parameters: your_favorite_attribute
```

Comment: Perfect @eirikir, it saves the record now, thank you! However, it does not save the id of the conference: 

(`rails c`)

`pry(main)> ConferencesMember.last`

`ConferencesMember Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "conferences_members".* FROM "conferences_members"  ORDER BY "conferences_members"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<ConferencesMember:0x007fcc61da1e68 id: 5, member_id: 70, conference_id: []>`

***But the log shows the selected conference ids...***

Comment: awesome, I could save the ids. In case to update the check_boxes, do you have any idea how I could do this?

Comment: What do you mean "In case to update the check_boxes"?

Comment: If I go to my edit page, the previously selected check_boxes are all unchecked. How to make them sync with de db and retrieve which one is checked?

Comment: @ViniciusMartinson how is `@all_conferences` defined?

Comment: `@all_conferences = Conference.all`

Comment: Any help would be awesomely appreciated @eirikir, sorry for insisting.